# I am trying to use index and match in VBA

Tags: vba, indexing, match

I am very new to vba and I apologize for the (many) mistakes I have made in the code below. I get an error when I set the `x` and `y` variables, but also when I try and run the index and match combination. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Public Sub indexandmatch()

Dim x As Range
Dim y As Range
Dim mycells As Range
Dim p As Variant

'workbooks(1) is the master workbook where I am trying to get the information from the other reports to be entered in to

Application.Workbooks(1).Activate

x = Application.Workbooks(2).Worksheets(1).Range("H:H")
y = Application.Workbooks(2).Worksheets(1).Range("I:I")

'range v is where I would like the values to be entered in the master

For Each mycells In Range("V:V")    
  p = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(x, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(mycells.Offset(0, -11).Value, y), 0)
  mycells = p.Value
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Need to use Set when assigning object variables

Comment: "I get an error" means nothing - you need to [edit] your question to *include the specific error you're getting*, and exactly *where* in the code it's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must `Set` any object variable, as `range` ones are

then use `Application` object functions that wraps possible error as returned value, so that you can check it with `IsError()` function and proceed correspondingly

finally avoid `Select`/`Activate` pattern and use fully qualified range references

```
Public Sub indexandmatch()
    Dim x As Range
    Dim y As Range
    Dim mycells As Range
    Dim p As Variant

    'workbooks(1) is the master workbook where I am trying to get the information from the other reports to be entered in to

    Set x = Workbooks(2).Worksheets(1).Range("H:H")
    Set y = Workbooks(2).Worksheets(1).Range("I:I")

    'range v is where I would like the values to be entered in the master

    For Each mycells In Workbooks(1).Worksheets("myMasterWorksheetName").Range("V:V") '<--| use fully qualified (up to worksheet and workbook) range reference. (change "myMasterWorksheetName" to you actual master workbook relevant worksheet name
        p = Application.Match(mycells.Offset(0, -11).Value, y)
        If Not IsError(p) Then
            p = WorksheetFunction.Index(x, p, 0)
            If Not IsError(p) Then mycells = p
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more specific with the error. Thank you very much user3598756. I still get an error and I'm not too sure why, when I run the code it returns 'Run-time error 424': object required and highlights the 'mycells = p.value' part of the code. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault: there was a `.Value` too much. see edited answer. if it solves your question you may want to mark it as accepted. thank you!

Comment: There is no error message and the macro runs, but for some reason no values are returned in col V:V. I have checked for basic errors e.g. spelling of sheet name, num of cols from mycells to lookup value for match, but they all seem ok. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: you have to step through your code and see what's going on: 1) place your cursor inside any statement of your sub 2) press F8 and have the macro start and highlight the first statement to be executed 3) use Immediate Window (CTRL+G to pop it out) and query relevant variables like typing `?p` (or `?mycells.Address` or ?(mycells.Offset(0, -11).Value`) pressing return and watching the returned value 4) press F8 to skip to the following statement

Comment: p = Application.Match(mycells.Offset(0, -18).Value, y) = empty. When I step into the sub this is what I get. Is the fact that it's empty the problem?

Comment: what does `?IsError(p)` return?